# ¿Cómo realizo una consulta en un tiempo x con php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente codigo para listar los usuarios que se encuentran suscritos a mi pagina.

```
<?php
public static function registrados($usuario){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where nombre = :nombre and apellido = :apellido";
        self::getConexion();

        $resultado = self::$cnx->prepare($query);


        $resultado->bindValue(":nombre", $usuario->getnombre());
        $resultado->bindValue(":apellido", $usuario->getapellido());

        $resultado->execute();

        if($resultado->rowCount() > 0){

            $filas= $resultado->fetch();
            if($filas["nombre"]==$usuario->getnombre() && $filas["apellido"] == $usuario->getapellido()){

                return true;

            }
        }else{

                return false;

        }
?>
```

Quiero que si desde otra parte se haga una actualización o una inserción de datos, se actualice la información, y se muestre en pantalla.

Se que existe una forma de hacer con jquery, de manera asincronica... Pero, no conozco un ejemplo o un código que explique el como hacerlo, como en este caso sencillo, en el que solo necesito que me muestre en pantalla la información de el nombre y apellido de un usuario que se ha suscrito a una página...

Tomé como referencia el estado de una persona de twitter. Cada esa persona publica uno nuevo twit, se apila en la lista como el primero. Y así pasa instantáneamente en la pantalla de otros usuarios que lo siguen, sin necesidad de dar F5 para recargar la página y ver los últimos eventos publicados por la persona.

Comment: Vos querés que desde el lado del cliente chequee esa función de php y si es verdadero o falso muestre cierta información en pantalla?

Comment: Tomé como referencia el estado de una persona de twitter. Cada esa persona publica uno nuevo twit, se apila en la lista como el primero. Y así pasa instantáneamente en la pantalla de otros usuarios que lo siguen, sin necesidad de dar F5 para recargar la página y ver los últimos eventos publicados por la persona.

Comment: Ah, lo que querés hacer es algo complejo como utilizar WebSockets para obtener real time los cambios y mostrarlos en el cliente cuando exista un cambio.

Comment: Exacto! Pero asi es como lo consulto? WebSockets? o existen otras librerias o o que lo complementen?

Comment: Claro WebSockets es una alternativa a eso que querés realizar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar un Interval que cada cierto tiempo este llamando tu funcion de php

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   $.ajax({
    url: "tuUrl/tuFuncion",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json', // added data type
    success: function(res) {
        //more code
      }
   });
}, 3000);
```